# Parsing C++ String

Tags: c++

I'm attempting to parse data from a exported text file from a database. I want to extract the data from the string and run a algorithm on it. I first tried using sscanf since that is what I'm familiar with, even though it probably isn't the best choice. Any help would be very much appreciated. I was getting very confused with some of the information I found online, for example the Boost Library. Here is just one row of data I'm attempting to parse. Ask any questions you need to, thanks.

```
1;3;8;"Fitted 1MX Stretch Cotton Shirt";"Berry";59.9;"http://www.express.com/clothing/men/fitted-1mx-stretch-cotton-shirt/pro/0303885/cat1390003"
```

Here is the order of the data, with data types (if important) and the semicolon is a delimiter.

```
int;int;int;string;string;double;string
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to split your string. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/split-a-string-in-c).

Then, having a vector with fixed size (compare its length it to validate your string) you only need to get ints or doubles with `std` functions:

- stod
- stoi
- stof

Defined in `<string>` header.